# android gcm when client get a message from gcm it crashed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Every time i send GCM messages to my client from my python server i get the followoing error:

logcat- android studio: 
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ozblumenfeld.myapplication2, PID: 22895
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.MyGcmListenerService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MyGcmListenerService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file

I added to manifest file:

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

and permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

and class MyGcmListenerService :

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
```

Comment: check package name for MyGcmListenerService. If it is wrong , it will not work

Comment: try to clean and build project again

Comment: same package name...

Comment: its not help to clean and build

Comment: are you quite sure that your MyGcmListenerService is in the com.example package?

Comment: getting the same error .... unable to solve it .. could you solve it?